# Laravel 5.5 Rest Api

Tags: laravel, rest, api

I am creating a Laravel Application that supports mobile app and normal blade.
**my Big problem of how to differentiate between return view and return json**
there is a lot of opinion of how to organize the code I'd like to know what is the best practice for my case.

1- Create Different Controllers 1 for web other for mobile ( kills DRY concept )
2- Create 1 Controller for mobile return json and call it's functions from the web controller 
3- Create service class contains the logic and create 2 controllers and inject an object in the constructore  EX : [ Services/UserService.php ] [ UserController.php ] [ Api/UserController.php ]
which way should i Follow 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the code logic in the same controller@method and use `wantsJson` to determine Accept header and build an appropriate response

```
// build $responseData

if (Request::wantsJson()) {
    return response()->json($responseData);
}
else {
    return view('view')->with($responseData);
}
```

Comment: That's a nice way to solve it, but makes the code more complicated (imagine that some endpoints won't be so simple and may have several differences between api response and web response. I prefer to create two controllers under different namespaces: `App\Http\Controllers\Api` and `App\Http\Controllers\Web`. You'll have more files but cleaner controller methods. Also you can create this namespace separation for Requests

Comment: @EliasSoares so you mean that to rewrite all the code in both controllers? or to operate the logic in the external class and use it in both?